# Why use Optcoupler + Mosfet?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, wiring, opto-isolator, converter

I saw this project: http://diyhacking.com/arduino-lamp-dimmer/ which I'm interessted to(except that I will have to use some 24V, still enough to hurt the Raspberry Pi).

There is several things that I'm not sure to understand:

- The optocoupler is used to isolate the 5V from the 230V(24V in my case), ok
- The MOSFET is used to normaly used to command an higher voltage with a lower voltage.

So what I don't understand is why we need the MOSFET since the optocoupler already receive some 230V(24V)?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at the optocouplers datasheet and the amount of current that you need for this to run.

Comment: If you're working with 24VDC, and it shares a ground with the RPi, there's really no reason to use an optocoupler.

Answer (score 1):

It adds another layer of protection even with 24V. If you screw up, screwdriver or test probe slips and shorts two connections together (or the wrong ground connection opens up) you're much less less likely to ruin your micro board. Your choice, there's not a human safety reason if the 24V has proper galvanic isolation as well as a common ground.

Since the 4N35 is so very painfully slow, using it degrades the switching of the MOSFET. This could be dealt with by using a somewhat better part and/or squaring up the signal on the other side of the barrier, but I think this is a major downside.

Real product designs would probably not use the opto unless there was some reason to keep a noisy 24V supply completely separate. In development, it's not uncommon to temporarily add isolation from mains or high power supplies. Or maybe just add some 10K resistors and a buffer.

It tends to ruin your day if excessive voltage finds its way into the wrong place and destroys the test object and your computer motherboard at the same time!

Comment: Ok, so if I just want to use my 5V output(3.3V in fact) to command a 24V motor(fan), what should I use(since I will do some PWM on this)

Answer (score 0):

The collector current for the 4N35 Opto-coupler is only rated to 100mA,
if the circuit you are controlling is going to consume more current than 100mA
You will need a to use a MOSFET to sink the current.

someone mentioned not needing to use opto-coupler with a 24v circuit.
it can be done, but it is best practice to isolate all LV control lines from higher voltages where possible to avoid damaging your control logic.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is it required to use all his capacitor in my case? I mean with DC-DC and a lower voltage.

Answer (score 0):

For RPi I use a ULN2003, strictly because I happened to have some laying around. Coincidental, I'm going to 24V as well, and sharing gnd from 24v supple with RPi.

Real simple

Most pages say to use the opto-couplers, and probably best practice.

Comment: Seems nice! Can you indicate me if this is the right reference? Does this allow you to make PWM?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the link: http://www.digikey.ch/product-detail/fr/ULN2003AIN/296-16971-5-ND/653041

Comment: also, how do I know which opto-coupler to use?